# How to "touch" a parent model of a `belongs_to` association only if certain conditions are met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, touch

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to "touch" a parent model of a `belongs_to` association only if certain conditions are met.

For example, at this time I have:

```
belongs_to :article,
  :touch => true
```

I would "touch" the parent model only if it is "public". That is, the `Article` class has an attribute named `access` (`@article.access` => `public` or `private`) and I would like to check this value before "touching": if this value is *not* `public`, then "touch" it!

**Is it possible to make that "directly" in the `belongs_to` association statement? If so, how?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try lambda as you said but I'm not sure if its going to work. Something like this:

```
belongs_to :article, :touch => Proc.new{|o| o.article && o.article.public }
```

According to the [implementation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/add_touch_callbacks#) maybe you can try to return `nil` instead of `false` in the proc, when it's not available

```
belongs_to :article, :touch => Proc.new{|o| o.article && o.article.public ? true : nil }
```

If this doesn't works use a before save callback like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  before_save :touch_public_parent

  def touch_public_parent
    article.touch if article && article.public?
  end
end
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

**Update #1**

The relevant part from `add_touch_callbacks`:

```
if touch_attribute == true
  association.touch unless association.nil?
else
  association.touch(touch_attribute) unless association.nil?
end
```

So if you pass true, then does a simple touch on `updated_at` attribute. If you pass a field name then updates that field unless you pass `nil`. If you pass nil doesn't updates nothing. That's why I said that maybe you can try the second version of `belongs_to` association.

Comment: There is no documentation related to the `add_touch_callbacks` method you linked in your answer... can you say some more about that (eg: how it works)?

Comment: Thank you very much. See you the next question/answer!

Comment: You're welcome, is it working with the `belongs_to` association?

Comment: I have not tested the first and second code or the last one. I just tried the third one ("If this doesn't works use a before save callback like this" [...]).

Comment: I think this answer is outdated... In the source for the add_touch_callbacks method on Rails 3.2.13 there's no nil check for the attribute...

Comment: It seems that there is still a nil check on the `record` see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Builder/BelongsTo/add_touch_callbacks

Comment: Its worth mentioning that the `add_touch_callbacks` method adds the hooks on `after_save`, `after_touch`, and `after_destroy` rather than `before_save` as indicated in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply touch with a condition in a belongs_to association.

There is a way which is a bit hacky but will work directly with a belongs_to association,

**This may not be the recommended way**

```
class YourModel
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :public_article, :class_name=> "Article", 
             :foreign_key => "article_id", 
             :conditions => {:public => true} , :touch => true 
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to use some `Proc`/`lambda` in the `:touch` option value?

Comment: no you can't use a proc or a lambda, quoting from documentation, ":touch => If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute."

Comment: I just opened another question in order to reach another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872045/there-is-a-way-to-handle-after-save-and-after-destroy-equally.