# There is a way to handle `after_save` and `after_destroy` "equally"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, callback

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know if it is possible to handle `after_save` and `after_destroy` callbacks "equally". That is, I need to run same methods for both `after_save` and `after_destroy` callbacks.

At this time I must handle those callbacks separately even if those accomplish to the same thing:

```
after_save do |record|
  # Make a thing
end

after_destroy do |record|
  # Make the same thing as in the 'after_save' callback
end
```

So, **there is a way to handle `after_save` and `after_destroy` "equally"?**

Comment: Call the same method from both?

Comment: @Dave Newton - Methods are literally the same.

Comment: I understand that--that's why I said call the same method from both, whether you're using the form in your post, or from a method reference as in the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of a block give `after_save` and `after_destroy` a method name of your model as a symbol.

```
class ModelName < AR
  after_save :same_callback_method
  after_destroy :same_callback_method

  def same_callback_method
    # do the same for both callbacks
  end
end
```

Comment: A class is defined with the `class` keyword, not the `def` keyword.

Answer (score 10):

To execute the same callback after both saving and destroying, you can use `after_commit`

```
after_commit do |record|
  # Is called after creating, updating, and destroying.
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit

Comment: It's my experience that this only works when the operation that triggers the event is wrapped in a transaction block, at least in Rails >= 3.2. It won't be called otherwise.

Comment: This is not the same. In `after_save` transaction has not been commited yet, in `after_commit` transaction is already commited.

Comment: `*_commit` is only triggered in a transaction block. It doesn't trigger when you `save`.

Comment: On Rails 5 as of 2018, *_commit is triggered regardless of whether there is a transaction block. So this answer is good!

Comment: Unless I'm quite mistaken, `after_commit` is NOT equivalent to `after_save` plus `after_destroy`, and this answer is incorrect. See [this piece of documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-save+and+destroy+are+automatically+wrapped+in+a+transaction) for details.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :my_callback
  after_destroy :my_callback

  private
  def my_callback
    #Do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, `protected` might be preferred to `private`