# Callback after_[anything]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've faced a situation, when I need to fire a callback for any event of the model. It's about cache reseting. I have `Follow` entity, where `follower_id` and `following_id`. If something happens with this entity (`create`/`update`/`destroy` and anything else that is possible) I need to reset some specific cache for both `follower` and `following`.

Right now I've finished with:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :reset_cache
  after_destroy :reset_cache

  def reset_cache
    ...
  end
end
```

Questions:

1. Does this cover all possible cases which can happen with model object?
2. Is there any one line approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: There are about 10 activerecord callbacks (which are easily googlable, btw). And no, I don't think there is one "blanket" callback

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's why I asked my question. Yes I've already googled them. And the questions is -- whether these 2 callbacks cover everything? Is there any better way? (my goggling shown me that it's the best I can do)

Comment: At a glance, this _should_ cover most of the persistence, yes. Maybe you need to add commit/rollback here too? :shrug:

Comment: commit/rollback is a good point, but I expect that these two should cover them. Still not sure, but I haven't seen any transactions for this model

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/23150192/297087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one line approach

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :reset_cache, on: [:update, :destroy]

  def reset_cache
  end 
end
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html